# Is there a way to specify a conditional type hint in Python?

Tags: python, types, type-hinting

Suppose the following code:

```
from typing import Union


def invert(value: Union[str, int]) -> Union[int, str]:
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return int(value)
    elif isinstance(value, int):
        return str(value)
    else:
        raise ValueError("value must be 'int' or 'str'")
```

It is easily seen that a `str` input leads to an `int` output and vice versa. Is there a way to specify the return type so that it encodes this inverse relationship?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There isn't really a natural way to specify a conditional type hint in Python at the moment.

That said, in your particular case, you can use [`@overload`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#function-overloading) to express what you're trying to do:

```
from typing import overload, Union

# Body of overloads must be empty

@overload
def invert(value: str) -> int: ...

@overload
def invert(value: int) -> str: ...

# Implementation goes last, without an overload.
# Adding type hints here are optional -- if they
# exist, the function body is checked against the
# provided hints.
def invert(value: Union[int, str]) -> Union[int, str]:
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return int(value)
    elif isinstance(value, int):
        return str(value)
    else:
        raise ValueError("value must be 'int' or 'str'")
```

Comment: That's too bad that Python doesn't have conditional types. As an example, Typescript has this feature: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types. Hopefully Python will too in the future.

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't have"? It's the same standard lib `typing` that you use for type annotations